# This edit (odd use of quote feature for "highlighting") doesn't seem right?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

Is [edit #3 on this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/724633/revisions) a valid edit?

It doesn't seem to make much sense to me; the OP wasn't actually quoting that paragraph from anywhere. The editor left the comment "Highlighting", but that doesn't seem correct.

I did not attempt to revert the edit because 1. I don't know if you guys have some customary use of quote blocks that I don't know about, and 2. The editor has enough rep that I presume he did the right thing. So, due to low confidence, I left it alone.

Comment: Many people use blockquote to visually distinguish some parts of the post, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10500/when-should-i-use-for-writing/10501#10501).

Comment: Edit by the same user [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/723477/revisions) looks more strange. They've added the `>` in the title, too. In any case, I have pinged the editor on the main and gave a link to this thread in a comment.

Comment: @MartinSleziak There's [another](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/722331/revisions) where the entire post was "highlighted", which seems equally odd since lack of contrast makes the "highlight" lose its significance. (My intention isn't to single this user out, they just happen to have an easily accessible list of such examples.)

Comment: @JasonC I think the edit you mention in your comment is far more questionable than the one in the original post.

Comment: It seems a bit nitpicky to edit something like this into someone else's post.

Comment: Let me just say this (in case the user who edited those posts read this, and also to encourage other editors.) We all appreciate effort to improve quality of the posts on this site by editing them, adding formatting, correcting typos etc. Not all users would make the same changes or consider the same things worth editing. But that's ok: we are all different, [we are all individuals](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079470/quotes?item=qt0471966).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was briefly discussed before: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10500/  Yes, the HTML tag is `<blockquote>`, so using it for visual separation of question from surrounding material is somewhat improper. But this usage quite common, in fact it predates Math.SE itself: the [model question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/883) on MathOverflow (written at the early days of the site) uses `>` to isolate the actual question.

By the way, SE itself promotes the use of `<blockquote>` for something other than quotes: namely, [spoilers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71396/251274) are realized as `<blockquote class="spoiler">`.

Personally, I think that mimicking a $\LaTeX$ environment in MarkDown is easy enough.

**Question**. *Is every finitely generated foo isomorphic to bar?*

After all, we don't usually see highlighted blocks of text in mathematical writing, apart from  some low-level undergraduate textbooks.

---

It may be more semantic to use HTML headers, but the choice SE gives us is between

## Way too big

### Still too big

#### Smaller than regular bold

Comment: @JasonC That said, consider that SE developers themselves decided to use blockquote for spoilers, which are usually *not* quotes.  (I just added this to the answer).

Comment: On the topic of your username: It's fine, but it does mean I double-check your account every time I forget about you and see your username, to make sure it's not a spam account.

Comment: @AlexBecker Sorry about the trouble, but I hope that the 3K+ reputation shown next to said username should alleviate the concern.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills It's no problem :)